# Grep command, looking for a capital first letter, no digits and a few native chars

Tags: regex, grep

I am working on a script to check if string is a proper person's name: first character must be capital, no digits and allowable native chars.
this is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
INPUT="$1"
echo "$1" | grep -qE  '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]].*[^0-9].*\ą\ę\ć\ź'

if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]; then
   echo "$1 is a valid name"
else
   echo "$1 is not a valid name"
fi
```

Comment: this are native characters, expected in somebodys name in Polish, I print them as they are...

Comment: I might delete this ".*\ą\ę\ć\ź'" condition, leave only first letter to be capital and no digits

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: John is ok, but: john, john44, 44john are not ok

Comment: Isn't `^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+$` all you need assuming your locale setting is correct? That'd exclude `McDonald`, `O'Grady`, etc. of course.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) #15 and #17

Comment: Thank you Ed, still fighting with locale. Supposing I'd like to have one+ of "ł".   '^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+$ . * ł +$' does not want to work.